# I've just downloaded ADT for Android development, where does it go?

Tags: linux, installation

I have just started using Ubuntu with XFCE. I downloaded the latest version of the Android Developer Tools from Google, and now I'm trying to figure out where I can put it. On Windows, I'd just unzip it to my C drive and rename the root folder "adt", and be on my merry way. But I can't figure out where it would go on Linux.

- Putting it in the **root "/" folder** doesn't seem like an option.
- **/usr/bin** and **/usr/local/bin** look like they're disallowed.
- I really don't want to keep this in my **Download** folder!

Comment: Have you tried Android Studio?

Comment: @AndreaGottardi It still leaves me with the "where does it go?" problem. But yeah, it looks cool :)

Comment: can't you simply move it from `Download` to another folder you like?

Comment: Depends if it should be available only for you or for all users of the linux system.
If it's for all users then /usr/local/bin (via sudo). If it's only for you, then something like /home/<myuser>/bin and then add it to the search path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu, just like on Windows, you can decide where you want to install/place applications, including the developer tools, and it is entirely up to you to keep your disk organized how you best see fit. Places like /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin tend to be protected, since changes there can have system-wide effects, but the protection is nominal

Personally, I like to keep my development tools separate, and restricted to a dev account on my machine, so I'd go with something like ~/devtools.

Comment: Took your advice, made a folder ~/Programs to put my software in. Thank you. (And I just found out "~" turns into "/home/myusername/".

Comment: that sounds like a safe starting point. as you learn more, you'll want to put some things in other directories. check out the wikipedia article for a good primer on what the conventions are: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_directory_structure